# Multiple set Interval time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

Here in this animation I've made two functions for two balls, but there is no second ball I am getting in this canvas. 
My code for both balls-

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    //ctx.beginPath();
    //ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    //ctx.closePath();
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 20, 20);
    ctx.fill();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    bounce();
}
function draw2()

{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    bounce();
}
```

Calling of functions-

```
    function init() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

        return setInterval(draw, 10);
return setInterval(draw2,20);
                   //This is how i am calling both function 

}
```

Can we do this in Javascript?

**Expecting result-**

Both balls are coming from same position, I want when first ball bounces in canvas frame, just after 10 milliseconds another ball from `draw2 ()` should come in frame and act the same.

Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/B6XZC/4/

Comment: Each time you call your draw functions you are clearing your canvas. That is why you only see one ball.

Comment: Actually your first `return` statement will stop the second setInterval from ever being executed.

Comment: Is this valid?  return setInterval(draw, 10,draw2,20);

Comment: It is valid, but code after a previous return statement will never be executed.

Comment: @ManojKumar: No. `setInterval` has only two arguments

Comment: @Bergi, If i am wrong, leave comment. Javascript gives us flexibility to use multiple functions at a time, though if setInterval time is a function then it can be used multiple times. Is that right?

Comment: @ManojKumar: Yes, but you need to actually use it multiple times. Do not `return` after executing it the first time, as pebbl mentioned

Comment: @ManojKumar - apologies, I hadn't spotted the fact that you were attempting to run both `draw` and `draw2` in one `setInterval`. This is not valid... however you can pass more parameters than two to `setInterval` (at least in modern browsers) -- any arguments beyond the first two will be passed as arguments to the function polled by `setInterval`. So your `setInterval(draw, 10, draw2, 20)` code will run, but it will poll `draw` (as close to) every 10ms (as possible), and pass `draw2` and `20` as the first two arguments of `draw`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working you will need to separate out your draw functions from your canvas clearing code, and have a tick/polling loop that is separate from the time you want your balls to appear.

You might as well use the power of JavaScript constructors to help you with your balls.

```
function ball( ctx, x, y, dx, dy ){
  this.img = ? /// you'll have to set your image, whatever it is.
  this.x = x||0;
  this.y = y||0;
  this.dx = dx||0;
  this.dy = dy||0;
  this.draw = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
  }
  this.tick = function(){
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    this.draw();
  }
}
```

And then use the following to handle drawing.

```
function clear( ctx, cnv ){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
  /// a faster way to clear can be: 
  /// cnv.width += 0; 
  /// or:
  /// cnv.width = cnv.width;
}

/// you should always have a core loop that delegates to other functions/objs
function loop( cnv, ctx, balls ){
  clear(ctx, cnv);
  for( var i=0; i<balls.length; i++ ){
    balls[i].tick()
  }
}

function init() {
  var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
  /// create the first ball and add it to your ball list
  var balls = [new ball(ctx,50,0,1,1)];
  /// 10ms wait before the extra ball is added
  setTimeout(function(){balls.push( new ball(ctx,100,0,1,1) );},10); 
  /// this will be your animation loop
  return setInterval(function(){loop(cnv, ctx, balls)}, 10);
}
```

The above has been hand-typed and not tested, and could be greatly improved.. but it should work and give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Both `draw()` and `draw2()` clear the canvas, so you will only see the last update. Also you have a single global `x`,`y`,`dx`, and `dy`, which means both your balls are drawn at the exact same position forever.